# Product attribute with store labels

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, frontend, eav-attributes

Is there any way to add product attribute with different store labels through **Magento2** setup script?

If we pass 'label'  it only assign default label of the attribute. I tried with **frontend_label** but that didn't worked.

```
$options =             [
        'type' => $type,
        'backend' => $input == 'multiselect'? 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend' : '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => $attributeLabel,
        'frontend_label' =>  array(0=>$attributeLabel,1=>$attributeLabel.' test1',2=>"",3=>"",4=>"",5=>$attributeLabel.' test5',6=>"",7=>"",8=>""),
        'input' => $input,
        'class' => '',
        'source' => in_array($input, ['text', 'textarea', 'multiselect'])
            ? '' :'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
        'global' => $is_Global ? \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL : \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'searchable' => true,
        'filterable' => $isFilter,
        'comparable' => true,
        'visible_on_front' => $showOnProductPage,
        'used_in_product_listing' => $usedInProductListing,
        'unique' => false,
        'group' => $group,
        'apply_to' => '',
        'wysiwyg_enabled' => $wysiwyg,
    ];



    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        $attributeCode,
        $options
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get the labels of custom attributes store wise :

```
$attribute = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute')->load($id);

$labelStoreWise = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
```